# SSIS ProtectionLevel

Tags: sql-server, ssis

So SSIS 2012 requires all your packages and your project to have the same ProtectionLevel.  We have a workflow where we can't store secrets in our packages but configure all our connection strings at runtime.  T

The tricky part is debugging these packages in Visual Studio requires you to either exclude all packages you are not working on and manually setting ProtectionLevel on the working packaging and project, or the more cumbersome approach of setting ProtectionLevel on all packages every time.  In a project with 20 packages like we have this is a chore.  Anybody have any good workflow for debugging SSIS packages while maintining a DoNotSaveSensitive ProtectionLevel?

Comment: If understood your question correctly then try to use configurations while your are using DoNotSaveSensitive.

Comment: I am using project deployment which doesn't allow you to use configurations http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx  Out infrastructure is built around setting SSIS package and project parameters dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I would create Project Parameters to store the connection strings:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213214.aspx

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Connection strings from Connection Managers get automatically exposed as Project parameters see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/22/parameterized-connection-managers.aspx).  In effect all we are doing is setting those Project parameters.  I guess I'm trying to have my cake (DoNotSaveSensitve) and eat it too (let me easily save the connection string when debugging in IDE).  It just stinks that you have to change the ProtectionLevel of every single package.

Comment: Dont you just fix it once and then save it?

Comment: when we check it in we need to check in as DoNotSaveSensitve as per policy of not storing secrets in code. Effectively undoing any credentials you may have entered.

Comment: I would store the credentials in the Project Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in project deployment model?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx

It should just work this way.

All packages same level and you set the connection strings in the environment on the server. I deploy mine to prod with localhost connection using Windows auth and the server magically does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a test project with just the package you want to test? Then you don't have to change protection level for each package.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to have two projects in Visual Studio: one with DontSaveSensitive and another one with the protection level desired.